# Change Background image in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, background, resources

I'd like to change the background image of my WPF application by a button. I know how to do it using WindowsForms, but in WPF I failed.
I found a solution already, but that solution would copy my background images to the output folder next to the Application.exe
This is not really a solution that I desire. I would like to have the images stored inside my application.

Can somebody explain me detailed what I need to do [how to add the images to the program, especially the resource-properties, how to access them in C#....]. It seems like I am too stupid to set it up correctly :P

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, add a **Folder** to your Solution (Right click -> Add -> Folder), name it something like *"Resources"* or something useful.

Then, simply add your desired image to the folder (Right click on folder -> Add -> Existing item).

Once it's been added, if you click on the image and open the **Properties** window (Alt+Enter), you'll see the **Build Action** is set to **Resource** and the **Copy to Output Directory** is set to **Do not copy**.

You can reference the image in C# using the following code:

```
this.Background = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/YourApp;component/YourFolder/YourImage.png"));
```

Or in **XAML**:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/YourApp;component/YourFolder/YourImage.png" ... />
```

Or:

```
<Image Source="/YourApp;component/YourFolder/YourImage.png" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks alot, your solution worked perfectly. I only had to place the new BitmapImage inside a new ImageBrush

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Yourapp;component/yourimage.png")));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer guided me to the solution :)